# IntelliJ 2018.2.2 Weird behavior when editing a Grails project

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

While I am editing any Grails project using IntelliJ 2018.2.2 and I have more than one tab open with different files each, the hover gets stuck in one file different than the one I'm editing, also keyboard gets lock and I can't use arrow, Enter or Space keys.

I've already check log files produced by IntelliJ, I cannot figure out what's going on, please help me.

I have the following specs:

- Description:  Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
- Release:  16.04
- Codename: xenial
- RAM: DDR3 16gb
- SSD 240GB
- Intel® Core™ i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz × 4

Log file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p7h23WmE4j973EUjwUFy_q5y0fN-nXPP/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample project and the logs folder zipped (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Comment: thanks @CrazyCoder, I've already post my report to jetbrains, but no body answered me yet.

Comment: Just answered: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-198144